# sql query to find absent tables from database

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am using ORACLE database. 
**EDIT**:

I want only tables not present in a list, not all those tables in database.

Ex: In my database following tables are present:

```
a
b
c
d
e
r
s
```

I am being given a list of tables:

```
a
b
c
v
h
```

out of which i want to find out which tables are **absent(not present)** in my database.

so: a, b, c are those tables which are present in my database. So excluding these tables my answer will be:

```
v and h
```

**My answer is not d,e,r,s**

How can i write a query for this to find out?

Comment: you can query all_tables view in oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT a.table_name FROM (SELECT 'A' as table_name 
               FROM DUAL UNION
               SELECT 'B' as table_name 
               FROM DUAL UNION
               SELECT 'C' as table_name 
               FROM DUAL UNION
               SELECT 'V' as table_name 
               FROM DUAL UNION
               SELECT 'H' as table_name 
               FROM DUAL) a WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1 FROM DBA_TABLES b where b.table_name=a.table_name)
```

Comment: how can i give my list there (in place of your_list)

Comment: CREATE TABLE YOUR_LIST (TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(100));

Comment: Right now we dont have table, We have list contains table names

Comment: @madhu did you get my updated question? Any idea what can be my sql query?

Comment: @madhu this will give you the not exist table list

Comment: Note :-if you use an IDE like PLSQL developer you will have a restriction on the number of tables in the list

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH table_names AS ( 
   SELECT 'A' AS tname FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'B' FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'C' FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'D' FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'E' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT tn.tname
FROM table_name tn
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1  
                  FROM all_tables at
                  WHERE tn.tname = at.table_name);
```

The WITH part is just a different (re-usable) way of writing a derived table ("inline view").

Comment: ok but i did n't get `WITH table_names AS(` , where should i begin?

Comment: that's all there is, everything from WITH to the closing paren before SELECT comprises a "CTE", it's a virtual table the rest of the query can refer to.

Comment: @saroj: it's just there to build up a table "on-the-fly". You could just put that into the sub-select as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i have updated my question for better understanding, is your query telling that?

Comment: @saroj: why don't you just run it?

Comment: ya i run your query but I have a list of tables, in your query i have not used these tables, that's why it is showing lots of tables.

Comment: @saroj: see my updated answer. You just need to swap the tables in the main select and the sub-select

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it with the MINUS operator (summary below):

```
select table_name from table_list
minus
select table_name from db_tables
;
```

More fully:

```
with table_list as 
(     select 'A' table_name from dual    
union select 'B' table_name from dual
union select 'C' table_name from dual
union select 'V' table_name from dual
union select 'H' table_name from dual
) 
, db_tables as
(     select 'A' table_name from dual
union select 'B' table_name from dual
union select 'C' table_name from dual
union select 'D' table_name from dual
union select 'E' table_name from dual
union select 'R' table_name from dual
union select 'S' table_name from dual
)
select table_name from table_list
minus
select table_name from db_tables
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table_name FROM DBA_tables WHERE table_name IN (Yourlist comes here)
```

for example

```
SELECT table_name FROM DBA_tables WHERE table_name NOT IN ('a','b','c');
```

Comment: ya but by this i will get tables those are present in the list, i want to get tables those are absent of this list, any idea please

Comment: `by not in` i will get all tables those are not present in the list, i want that tables absent from this list, perhaps u r confusing, i have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the table and sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll to create a virtual column from your list.

The following should do the trick:

```
SELECT
    column_value AS missing_table_names
FROM
    TABLE(SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL('a','b','c','v','h'))
WHERE
    column_value NOT IN (
        SELECT
            table_name
        FROM
            ALL_TABLES
    );
```